# Insert a value in buffer in hex format

Tags: c++, windows

I have a binary file which has hex values in it. Eg `1d 31 30 2e 30 30 2e 38 33 5f 75 66 6c 78 3b 30`

I have a c++ project where I read the data and process the information using `ifstream`.

Now I want to modify a value in the buffer. Eg. `1d` should be changed to `0a`.

Following is my code. The problem here is I get the value as `a` instead of `0a`. How can I insert a perfect hex digit into the buffer.

```
void TestMethod()
{
    std::ifstream m_inputFile;
    m_inputFile.open("c:\\temp.bin", std::ofstream::in | std::ofstream::binary);

    char* buff = new char[300];
    m_inputFile.read(buff, 300);
    UpdateData(buff, 10);
}

void UpdateData(char* buffer, int val)
{
    int POSITION = 32;

    char capID[2];
    itoa(val, capID, 16);

    std::memcpy(&buffer[POSITION], &capID, sizeof(buffer[POSITION]));
}
```

Suggestions pls.
Thanks.

Comment: `'\x1D'` and `'\x0A'` are control characters, not hex digits. `'\x2E'` is the same as `'.'`. And so on. Many of the characters in the example are not hex digits. Not to mention that `'\x0A'` and `'\xA'` are exactly the same. I think that you may be confusing things.

Comment: I did not add my complete binary data. These are some header stuffs which will be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void UpdateData(char* buffer, int val)
{
    int POSITION = 32;
    char capID[3];  // 1 extra for terminating zero!!!!
    // use good old sprintf
    sprintf(capID, "%02x",  (val & 0xFF));
    std::memcpy(&buffer[POSITION], &capID, sizeof(buffer[POSITION]));
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks @wmc. Works perfectly for my requirement.